# Check if file is open in any application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

Is it possible to check if a file or bundle is opened by any Application? For example, lets say that I know that `/Users/Foo/AwesomeDocument.txt` exists and its open in `TextEdit`, can I reliable check from my app that the document is open?
I'm okay with solutions that only work with documents opened via `NSDocumentController`.

Comment: Oh come on, I don't want to start a bounty for every question I create...

Comment: Have you considered that you might have asked a difficult question?

Comment: @RobKeniger Yes, thats why I asked here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an NSTask to run the shell command `lsof | grep "Document.txt"` and then parse the results, though that method is kind of slow. I don't know of a native Cocoa way to achieve this.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work with files that are opened via `NSDocumentController` since it doesn't have the file handle open the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

For example, in Applescript:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set theDocument to document of window 1
    return theDocument
end tell
```

Comment: Not exactly, I want to check wether a known file is open, not what is currently open in TextEdit (so the reverse version of this would be awesome). It should also work across spaces =/

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set theDocuments to every document
    repeat with aDocument in theDocuments
        if (path of aDocument) as string is equal to "/test.txt" then
            display dialog "found"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still need it the other way around. Asking every app if the document is open is a bit of an overhead I don't really want, I would rather just use the path and know if the file is open somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 10.7 you may want to try something with [`NSFileCoordinator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFileCoordinator). Bare in mind thath not every app is bound to have [`NSFilePresenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFilePresenter) implemented and go the way with `NSDocument`.